# react-sortable-tree - How to get the search API working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to the API doc there needs to be a searchQuery prop which i've mentioned in my code but the search doesn't seem to be working

API doc doesn't explain how to implement it and the examples available online don't seem to be working on code sandbox.

The only article available which seems to explain search has incorrect code (duplicate props): https://frugalisminds.com/how-to-create-react-sortable-tree/

API Doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sortable-tree

Below is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SortableTree from "react-sortable-tree";
import "react-sortable-tree/style.css";

export default class Tree extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 
    this.state = {
      treeData: [
        { title: "Chicken", children: [{ title: "Egg" }] },
        { title: "Fish", children: [{ title: "fingerline" }] },
      ],
      searchString: ""
    };
  }

  handleSearchOnChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      searchString: e.target.value,
    });
  };
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: 400 }}>
        <input 
          type="search" 
          onChange={this.handleSearchOnChange} 
          className="form-control" 
        />
        <SortableTree
          searchQuery={this.state.searchString}
          treeData={this.state.treeData}
          onChange={treeData => this.setState([...treeData])}
          isVirtualized={false}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check [this](https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-sortable-tree/blob/master/stories/search.js)

Comment: Here is the working [example](https://frontend-collective.github.io/react-sortable-tree/?path=/story/basics--search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing a searchFocusOffset to highlight the found item and a searchMethod which can be custom defined inside render method as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SortableTree from "react-sortable-tree";
import "react-sortable-tree/style.css"; // This only needs to be imported once in your app

export default class Tree extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 
    this.state = {
      treeData: [
        { title: "Chicken", children: [{ title: "Egg" }] },
        { title: "Fish", children: [{ title: "fingerline" }] },
      ],
      searchString: ""
    };
  }
 
  render() {
    // Case insensitive search of `node.title`
    const customSearchMethod = ({ node, searchQuery }) =>
      searchQuery &&
      node.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      
    return (
      <div style={{ height: 400 }}>
        <input 
          type="search" 
          onChange={event => this.setState({ searchString: event.target.value })}
          className="form-control" 
        />
        <SortableTree
          searchMethod={customSearchMethod}
          searchQuery={this.state.searchString}
          searchFocusOffset={0}
          treeData={this.state.treeData}
          onChange={treeData => this.setState([...treeData])}
          isVirtualized={false}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```